# Determining standardised difference between two data vectors with negative values

Tags: matlab, standardization, group-differences, difference-in-difference

I am using Matlab to determine the standardised difference between a treated group, A, and a control (untreated) group, B, to eliminate the effect of size of baseline (B) value and to therefore determine whether absolute difference (A - B) is correlated to standardised difference. The data vectors are:

```
A = 18.40,6.06,12.46,25.25,60.00,30.77,48.95,35.77,29.73,38.40,36.36,35.33,20.18,82.46,34.25,10.83,49.08,25.00,63.06,-5.31,15.55,35.02,15.96
B = -2.40,-43.94,-2.36,-6.57,21.82,11.83,20.92,15.45,17.57,24.80,24.24,24,14.8,74.85,33.33,10.83,49.21,25.56,64.72,-5.54,16.39,40.11,36.17
```

I have simply been dividing each element in A by the corresponding element in B, however, this approach only works when dividing a positive number by a positive number. Is there a method for accounting for negative values when dividing A by B? Alternatively, would calculating relative change using the below formula be a better approach?

Relative change = (treated - untreated) / untreated x 100%

Or is there a more appropriate alternative approach I have not considered? I have produced a scatter plot of the raw data vectors with a linear regression line fitted:

[image]

The Matlab code used to produce the above plot is:

```
mdl = fitlm(B,A) % Fit a linear model to the data

figure()
hold on
scatter(B,A) % Plot data
x = [min(B) max(B)];
fplot(@(x) mdl.Coefficients.Estimate(2)*(x)+mdl.Coefficients.Estimate(1)) % 
Plot y=mx+c function using coefficients determined in the linear model
xlabel('untreated')
ylabel('treated')
title('Linear Regression Relation between Treated and Untreated')
legend('Data','Slope','Location','best');
```

Thank you for your time,

Laura

Comment: Could you explain why you want to divide?  Why not subtract?

Comment: Of course, I want to see whether the absolute difference is related to the baseline (control) level or whether it is independent

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're doing or why.  If you want to relate two things, then start with those two things: in this case, "absolute difference" and "baseline."  What is the concern about relative change or anything else?

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear. I want to determine whether a higher neutrophil count (B) correlates to a higher response of these same neutrophils in treated group A (elementwise). I thought relative change was the way to detect this? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: As you have noted, relative change is meaningless when some of the numbers are negative.  If you want to measure correlation, then measure it!  If by "correlates" you mean "there exists some kind of nontrivial relationship," then you're in the very general situation of attempting to model one variable in terms of another. Have you at least looked at their scatterplot?  What does it suggest about a relationship?

Comment: I have, please see the edited post

Comment: Thank you--but that's an unhelpful scatterplot.  Start with the *data* you collected rather than with the quantities you might have derived from them through subtraction or division. It will make things much clearer.  For instance, if you use `R` you could make the scatterplot quickly *via* `library(ggplot2); ggplot(data.frame(A=A, B=B), aes(B, A)) + geom_point(alpha=1/2, size=2) + geom_smooth()`

Comment: My apologies, please see the raw data scatter above with the code to produce this plot.

Comment: Thank you--that's much more helpful.  I mistrust the figure, though, because parts of it clearly are erroneous.  First, the line obviously is not the least squares fit of the points that are shown.  Second, $R^2$ obviously is much greater than the value of $0.056$ in the title--it should be about ten times as great. The problem stems from your calculations, which do not implement least squares fitting.  (What language are you using?) They appear to force the line through the origin, which seems inappropriate for your analysis.

Comment: Well spotted, I also thought the `R^2` was too low. This was a result of the linear regression function I was using to fit the data. I have now updated the Matlab code to use a function that does not force the regression line through the origin and uses ordinary least squares as the fitting method.

Comment: It looks fine now.  But doesn't that answer your original question?  You have just found a (significant) relationship between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: It does! I was making things more complicated than they needed to be. Thank you for all your help!